# Drone motor specifications

Tags: power, brushless-dc-motor

I came across a video where e bike is powered by a drone motor.

https://youtu.be/P5uUyUWpP_I?si=EbKb5CHgOntANXcf

I totally understand that it's possible via using appropriate gear ratios to convert RPM into torque.

What I don't understand is how can that small motor be 1000 watts?

My air conditioner is 1000 watts and consumes 1 unit per hour on home electricity meter.

I am sure this drone motor cannot consume fraction of it.

What is 1000 watts on air conditioner vs drone motor vs bike motor?

Comment: I have a 2.5 kW skateboard motor that I cannot quite wrap my fingers around. It spins at  small fraction of the drone motors speed. The one shown is on the small side for 1 kW BUT it's feasible.

Answer (score 0):

A watt is a watt so no difference there.

The size of a motor is largely dependent on frequency and by extension RPM. A low speed motor like your AC compressor will require a core large enough to take the half-cycle Vt/NA=B integral (V integral over T for your half-cycle) without saturating (B is your core flux density). For a usable core size, this pushes the number of turns high and thus thin wire diameter to fit within the winding area. This makes slow spinning motors large. You can cheat to some extent by increasing the number of poles, but there are limits and trade offs here.

If you go to ludicrous frequency and thus RPM, you can use a much smaller core and a few turns of very thick wire on the winding. The propellers on drones are very small so they need high speed anyway.

However, your drone motor will most probably have lower efficiency and relies on high level of forced air cooling from the propeller.

Comment: A watt is a watt. Does that mean in 1 hour drone motor will consume same power as airconditioner compressor? That seems ludicrous consumption.

Comment: @Alex Drones consume power at a ludicrous rate. Please check the battery energy capacity of one and the runtime and compute the average draw.

Comment: The drone motor spins at 30000RPM without a load. It consumes high current when it is stalled and is not spinning. Then you cannot calculate its power from max voltage time max current. My bike has no motor and it goes faster than the drone motor bike going downhill as shown in the video.